# The representation of $SU(2)$ as a polynomial function on $\mathbb C^2$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $A$ element of $SU(2)$ and $p$ a polynomial function of fixed degree $l$ on $\mathbb C^2$ (in other words, $p \in P_l(\mathbb C^2)$), then the polynomial representation of $A$ in $P_l(\mathbb C^2)$ is given by $$
p(A^{-1}v)
$$
where $v\in \mathbb C^2$. My question is why use $A^{-1}$, why not $p(Av)$? I would really appreciate if someone can explain in a beginner-friendly way - I am new in representation theory.

Comment: If you write up the definition of a group action then you will see that if you don't include the $^{-1}$ then rather than having $(gh).v = g.(h.v)$ you would get $(gh).v = h.(g.v)$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Is that the associative requirement for a group, thus $g$, $h$, and $v$ are all elements of a group?

Comment: This is the definition of a group acting on a set. I denote the group operation just by concatenation and the action by $.$. In your case you should take another matrix $B$ and compare what happens when $AB$ acts to what happens when first $B$ acts and then $A$ acts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map 
$$
 \pi : \mathrm{SU}(2) \to \mathrm{GL}(P_l(\mathbb C^2)), \quad (\pi(x)P)(z) = P(x^{-1}z)
$$
is required to be a homomorphism. You can check this by hand. If you write $x$ instead of $x^{-1}$ you loose this property.

Comment: So, if $y \in SU(2)$ then
$$
(\pi(xy)P)(z) = P(x^{-1}z)P(y^{-1}z)
$$
Is that right?
I personally think my equation above looks strange because the LHS is generally not commutative while the RHS, which is just the product between polynomials, must be commutative.

Comment: No, you don't get a product of polynomials. We have that $(\pi(x) \pi(y)P)(z) = (\pi(x)(\pi(y)P))(z) = (\pi(y)P)(x^{-1}z) = P(y^{-1}x^{-1}z) = P((xy)^{-1}z) = (\pi(xy)P)(z)$.

Comment: I get it, if I used $x$ instead of $x^{-1}$, I will get
$$
(\pi(x) \pi(y)P)(z) = (\pi(yx)P)(z)
$$

Comment: Yes, you are right.